# How do I plot $W(z^2)W(1/z)$ where $W(z)$ is the product log function and $z=x+yi$ in Desmos 3D?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, desmos

So I was trying to plot$$W(z^2)W(1/z)$$where $W(z)$ is the product log function and $z=x+yi$ in Desmos 3D (since Desmos recently(?) released a 3D version which is great for plotting 3D functions). I know the graph should look something like this:

[Top view:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxWla.png)

[image]

[Bottom view:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bw8m.png)

[image]

Mathematica code used to generate this graph:

```
ComplexPlot3D[ProductLog[z^2]ProductLog[1/z],{z,-10-10I,10+10I}]
```

however here's the problem I'm having when plotting this in Desmos 3D:

1. I can't put in $i=\sqrt{-1}$ into Desmos since it's not defined.
2. When I use $z=x+y$, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqLHG.png) happens:

[image]

which I verified to be the real plot of $$W(x^2+2xy+y^2)W(1/(x+y))$$using the following Mathematica code:

```
Plot3D[ProductLog[(x+y)^2]ProductLog[1/(x+y)],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]
```

[Mathematica input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkU09.png)

[image]

so my question is: What am I doing wrong to plot $W(z^2)W(1/z)$ where $W(z)$ is the product log function and $z=x+yi$ in Desmos 3D?

[Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/3d/d37f15cefd)